# Implementing database from UML

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys, uml

I recently modeled an UML diagram that basically involves associations. Let's say the code is:

```
public class Seller{
    private int idSeller;
    private String name;
    private String passw;
    private List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<Phone>();

    public Seller() {           
    }

    public Seller(int idSeller, String name, String passw, List<Phone>phones) {
        super();
        this.idSeller = idSeller;
        this.name = name;
        this.passw = passw;
        this.phones = phones;
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

and

```
public class Phone {
    private int idPhone;
    private String description;
    private String number; //will have some chars in it

    public Phone() {
    }

    public Phone(int idPhone, String description, String number) {
        super();
        this.idPhone = idPhone;
        this.description = description;
        this.number = number;
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

I don't want to limit the numbers of phones the sellers can have, moreover this is just a excerption of my whole code.

Now, I need to create my SQLite database and insert the data in it, but I'm a bit confused on how I'll represent the association from the UML to the database.

If I wasn't working with OO I would put a foreing key in the Phone table referring to the seller's id that owns the phone, but the concept of OO makes me doubt this is the right way to do it here.

I have good understanding of UML, but this is the first time I try to implement an UML diagram and load the data from a database. Can someone please help me saying what's the right way to do it?

Comment: Two downvotes and no explanations. Can someone please tell me what is wrong, so?

Comment: You will need a foreign key between the database tables. You've just experienced the Object-Relational impedance http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch

Comment: I liked this term "Object-Relational impedance" it representes exactly what happened to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you really need to read up on database theory.  This is an extremely simple schema to write-  pretty much a hello world of schemas.  Don't think it terms of UML or OO-  those are the wrong terms for thinking about data.  You need to think in terms of how the data makes sense to organize.  Its the programmer's job to map that into objects later.

You have two tables.  Table one is a table of Sellers. It has an id (which is your primary key), a name, a password (which should be stored in hash form, not in plaintext).  The second table is of phones.  It has an id (primary key), a number, and an owner field with type int that is a foreign key on the seller id.

When you do need to load the data into code-  first you load the seller structures (other than the array) by a query on table 1.  Then you query table 2 for all phones with a matching seller id, and loop over the returns adding it to your phone array.